# What is the connection in the use of ἀφανίζω in both Mt 6:16 and 6:19-20?

Tags: matthew, sermon-on-the-mount

In Craig Blomberg's article, "[On Wealth and Worry: Matthew 6:19-34—Meaning and Significance](http://faculty.gordon.edu/hu/bi/ted_hildebrandt/ntesources/ntarticles/ctr-nt/blomberg-wealthmat-ctr.pdf)",  *Criswell Theological Review* 6.1 (1992), 73-89, on p. 74 at footnote 7 he notes:

> There is... an important "catchword" connection between the uses of ἀφανίζω in 6:16 and 6:19-20. See A Sand, *Das Evangelium nach Matthaus* (Regensburg: Pustet,1986) 19-21."

The [verses in question](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Mt+6%3A16%3B+6%3A19-20&version=NASB;SBLGNT) read as follows:

> **Matt 6:16** Whenever you fast, do not put on a gloomy face as the hypocrites do, for they neglect their appearance [ἀφανίζουσιν] so that they will be noticed by men when they are fasting. Truly I say to you, they have their reward in full.
>
> **Matt 6:19** “Do not store up for yourselves treasures on earth, where moth and rust destroy [ἀφανίζει], and where thieves break in and steal. **20** But store up for yourselves treasures in heaven, where neither moth nor rust destroys [ἀφανίζει], and where thieves do not break in or steal;...

Can someone provide additional explanation as to this connection?

Comment: Thank you, David, for that much much much improved edit to the question.

Comment: FYI - I just emailed Dr. Blomberg to see if he can solve this riddle...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Dr. Blomberg:

> I was just pointing out that the text is more of a unity at this point than might meet the eye to the English reader.  There is no hidden meaning.